# How to Programme PIC Microcontroller without Using MPLAB X

Tags: dll, open-source, pic, plc, mplab

I am Making a MicroPLc and has choosen PIC24FJ series as controller. IN PLC World People use LAD, FBD, STL ,etc for Programming not c or c++.

There a Lot of Open software which converts PLC language to 'C'. My Question is how to convert that C code in .Hex file without Using MPLAB X . or is there any method of procedure by which we can Invoke XC 16 Compiler for compiling and generation .HEX File.

a Internet Search reveals there is an SDK for Mplab but that just help to Burn .Hex file in to the Chip. Nothing about converting 'c' to .Hex

Any suggestion or Link to an Api, Dll etc will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, in the PLC world I live in STL is completely outdated. LAD and FBD are used less and less. In our company we started using SCL/ST as default language. Siemens even sports C++ on PLC's lately.
PLC is more about robust hardware and long lasting support these days. I'd advise not to waste your time on implementing STL and the likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure exactly what you're asking for but do you just mean a toolchain to compile your C file into a hex binary file?

In that case you should be able to run the XC16 compiler from command line.
MPLAB X just generates a GCC makefile if I'm not mistaken.

Check the XC16 C Compiler manual:

http://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/techpub_sg/documents/devicedoc/en559023.pdf

And this resource may also be of use:

http://adamsiembida.com/how-to-compile-mplabx-projects-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will Look into it and Shall come back if More help is Needed.

Comment: Further, I also found that there is MPLAB X SDK API for Developers. also  XC16 compiler Source code. http://www.opensource4pic.org/content/content/xc-16-source.

Comment: Do you really need the compiler source?  Have a look at page 89 of the manual : it tells you howto drive the  compiler from the command line

Comment: Thanks for the Help. I found the Manual , Reading now shall come back if anyother help needed.